ERROR: BIOS/LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI-ONLY MEDIA
I am trying to boot my computer from a USB drive that I created using Rufus. The USB drive contains an Ubuntu ISO. When I attempt to boot from the USB, I receive the following error message:
ERROR: BIOS/LEGACY BOOT OF UEFI-ONLY MEDIA
This drive was created by Rufus.
It can boot in UEFI mode only but you are trying to boot it in BIOS/Legacy mode. THIS WILL NOT WORK!
...
Steps I Have Taken:

Created the USB drive with Rufus using the following settings:
i. Partition scheme: GPT
ii. Target system: UEFI (non-CSM)

Attempted to boot from the USB drive, resulting in the error message above.

Checked my BIOS settings and confirmed that the boot mode is set to BIOS/Legacy.


Question:
How can I resolve this error and successfully boot from the USB drive? Should I switch my system to UEFI mode, or recreate the USB drive with different settings? Any guidance on the best approach would be greatly appreciated.

The more pertinent question here is you you have Legacy enabled? That is ONLY for OSes that don't support UEFI, not the case here with Ubuntu.

If you have an UEFI system, generally better to use UEFI. And almost all systems since 2012 when Microsoft required UEFI with gpt partitioning on all systems for Windows 8 are UEFI. Only a few very early UEFI may work better with BIOS install. If only Linux you still can use the better gpt over old MBR which is only required for Windows in old BIOS mode. If old BIOS only system, better to not use Ubuntu but use a light weight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
I use Kubuntu which is lighter but more mid-eight.

There's an entry for this in the Rufus FAQ.
See https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/wiki/FAQ#user-content-ERROR_BIOSLEGACY_BOOT_OF_UEFIONLY_MEDIA
To resolve the issue, you need to do one of the 3 steps that were explicitly provided to you in the error message.
